# visual studio namespace class recognition error

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[image]

A class in "Assembly - CSharp" is not recognized or used by a class in another namespace.
The error I'm getting now is:
Unity Editor: The type or namespace name 'LogitechGSDK' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
IDE: Namespace does not correspond to file location

How do I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

have you setup the dependencies/references for the class not inside the "Assembly - CSharp"? If so you should add Assembly - CSharp to the depencies/references of the Assembly you want to use it in. Here is a link that could help you fix your Problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019